# Request returning a valid response payload but browser displays blank pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, browser, iis-7.5

We've just deployed our ASP.NET MVC app on a new server.

All the pages show up alright except one particular page that shows up blank on all browsers. However, a request to the said page returns a 200 HTTP status code and the browser, through displaying a blank white screen, shows the entire HTML in the page source.

The details of the deployment environment are:

1) Windows Server 2008 R2
2) IIS 7.5
3) ASP.NET MVC 4

Comment: When you save the source as HTML can you pull that page up successfully in a browser? Also, what does the console say? Anything?

Comment: Thank you, @DeweyOx. That was really helpful. I hadn't tried that. I see now that master page (Razor view engine layout) loads but the call to @@RenderBody does not return anything. The child page has valid HTML with jQuery code. The same page loads on other environments.

Comment: Make sure errors are set to display in your error handling setup in your global.asax - often on prod servers, this is turned off.